# Spread data across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` like this:

```
            name  value
2014-01-01  temp   10.0
2014-01-01     p  101.0
2014-01-02  temp   11.5
2014-01-02     p  100.0
```

I would like to build a new DataFrame with unique index
and with one column per data.

Something like `df2` :

```
            temp      p
2014-01-01  10.0  101.0
2014-01-02  11.5  100.0
```

My first idea was to create a new DataFrame using

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.unique(), columns=df['name'].unique())
```

and to use a for loop to populate this DataFrame

```
for col in df['name'].unique():
    df2[col] = df[df['name']==col]['value']
```

but I think that Pandas can do this much more efficiently.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment below by @scls, there may be a bug in pandas when using `pivot` to do this with a DataFrame that has duplicate entries in the index.

You need to use the modified version here to get it to work:

```
df.pivot(columns='name', index=df.index)['value']
```

Edit: the answer below appears not to work with duplicate entries in the index, which appears to be a bug when compared against the pandas documentation where it says that if `index` is omitted, the unique elements of the existing index will be used.

This is also problematic because in this case, using `set_index` followed by `unstack` will be very tedious, since one of the would-be index levels is already the index, and the other is not. We want to "append" `name` into the index, without needing to first pop the unnamed, existing index out of there, which can be done but leads to annoying, unreadable syntax.

Original answer: Use the facilities provided in the `pandas.DataFrame` [`pivot` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html), to pivot on the column that you want to serve as the categories.

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='name', values='value')
>>> 
variable    temp      p        

2004-01-01  10.0  101.0
2004-01-02  11.5  100.0
```

If you are having trouble with errors related to the index, try adding the index as part of the pivot:

```
df.pivot(index=df.index, columns='name', values='value')
```

This can optionally also be accomplished with the [function `pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) directly in the `pandas` module top-level namespace, as in:

```
pandas.pivot_table(df, ...)
```

if you don't want to call directly from the DataFrame under test.

Comment: I did `df.pivot(columns='name', index=df.index)['value']` because your code wasn't working (cannot label index with a null key)

Comment: Which version are you using? The docs for 0.14 say that `index` is optional and that unique values from the existing index will be used if it is omitted.

Comment: pd.__version__ returns 0.14

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a bug then. I believe somewhere when it is looking up the indices, it exhausts them. Meaning, once it consumes an index value, the same value becomes unavailable for consumption. In some of the documentation and associated other SO questions, it looks like some of the pandas devs try to deflect this by saying that `pivot` is a "reshape" operation, as opposed to something that alters the index. But that's not a satisfactory explanation: reshaping is exactly what one is trying to do when going from duplicate index entries to the widened-column version.